# 2 Questions, I cant seem to get rid of the each child should have an id error

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I cant seem to get rid of the each child should have an id error and secondly how can I access the href in the url data, I have managed to pull all the other data but for some reason I can not pull the href.

```
function Data() {
  const [Music, setMusic] = useState([], {});
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=100/json")
      .then((data) => {
        setMusic(data.data.feed.entry);
     console.log(JSON.stringify)})  
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    setSearch(event.target.value.toLowerCase());
  };

  const filtered = Music.length
    ? Music.filter(
        (music) =>
          music["im:name"]["label"].toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
          music["im:artist"]["label"].toLowerCase().includes(search)
      )
    : [];

  return (
    <div>
      <Nav onChange={handleSearch} placeHolder={"search title, artist"} />
      <article id="article" className="albums">
        <ul className="album-items">
          {filtered.map((Music) => {
            const { id } = Music;
            return (
              <div  className="album"><a href='/'></a>
                <li className="album-list" key={id.attributes["im:id"]}>
                  <SimplePopover Music={Music}>
                    <img
                      src={Music["im:image"][2].label}
                      alt={Music["im:name"].label}
                    />
                  </SimplePopover>
                </li>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </article>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move up the `key` property to the uppermost `div` (or any element you use) you are returning from the `map`

```
  <div  className="album" key={id.attributes["im:id"]}>
```